# Server Sockets Don't accept clients

Tags: java, sockets

I'm learning about sockets in java. I was able to connect a client socket to an online server, but I can connect them to my own server socket!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class Blargh2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket client = null;
        ServerSocket server = null;
        System.out.println("Line one reacehd!");
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(4445);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Line two reacehd!");
        try {
            client = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Accept failed: 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Line three reacehd!");
        try {
            server.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Accept failed: 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

The program reaches lines one and two but it never reaches line 3!
Can anyone help me solve this? Firewall also allows this connection...

Comment: Are you beware of the fact that your ServerSocket is running on port 4445?

Comment: How are you connecting in to your server? telnet?

Comment: How am I supposed to connect?
OK this is the first time I'm doing sockets. I thought that the only thing I have to do is to create the server, and then connect the socket by using the accept() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It never reaches line 3 because you need a remote TCP socket (although it can be local, for testing) to connect to your socket on port 4445. You accept endpoint sockets on the server, which are used for communication with the remote client. There is actually no client here, so it waits indefinitely or until a timeout on the `accept()` call.

Comment: I've defined a client socket: "Socket client=bull;" and then I try to connect it to the server using the accept() method. What should be changed in the code to make it work on local?

Comment: I added this: "client = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4446);" before the accept() method, and it worked!! Now I understand what you meant by "There's no client here!"...
About telnet: I've some questions. Is telnet a protocol? What does the telnet command do? Are these sockets using telnet? I'll appreciate your help if you answer these. Thank you so much.

Comment: Telnet just uses the standard line based protocol, which is why child protocols like or FTP, IRC or HTTP can be communicated over it. That means that lines are sent and received in their entirety. When you type something and press enter, it sends that line to the server, then the server sends something back. You should wrap your socket stream in the appropriate line-oriented abstractions to make life easy for yourself. Check this page out for more details: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/sockets.html

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code and after you see line 2 is executed, then run the windows command:

telnet localhost 4445

Then you should see your line 3 executed.

Comment: What is exactly happening when I telnet? And why doesn't the client connect only by using the accept() mathod?

Comment: telnet IS the client.  What you wrote is a server, you need to write a client as well to connect to that port.  Telnet connects to that port as a client.